# Restoring git reset even tho they dont show anymore on the repo

Tags: git, git-reset

Someone has done a `git reset --hard f7fe845` and they pushed it into a branch in the repo.

Now in that branch  we can't see any work done before that commit. Effectively loosing all work on that branch's work.

We need to revert that git reset and get the branch to the previous version, but at least on the git website or source-tree is like the other commits don't exist anymore.

Is there any hope to get the information back? How?

My branch is `feature/UAL-117`

```
[ec2-user@ame]$ git reflog
8c0136d HEAD@{0}: reset: moving to HEAD~1
f7fe845 HEAD@{1}: checkout: moving from develop to feature/UAL-117
f7fe845 HEAD@{2}: checkout: moving from feature/UAL-117 to develop
f7fe845 HEAD@{3}: checkout: moving from develop to feature/UAL-117
f7fe845 HEAD@{4}: checkout: moving from feature/UAL-117 to develop
f7fe845 HEAD@{5}: reset: moving to f7fe845df3efc0a6b79b4ccde50ab08fc542532f
6a03be3 HEAD@{6}: checkout: moving from develop to feature/UAL-117
f7fe845 HEAD@{7}: checkout: moving from f7fe845df3efc0a6b79b4ccde50ab08fc542532f to develop
f7fe845 HEAD@{8}: checkout: moving from feature/UAL-117 to f7fe845df3efc0a6b79b4ccde50ab08fc542532f
6a03be3 HEAD@{9}: pull: Fast-forward
24e9afe HEAD@{10}: pull: Fast-forward
d238450 HEAD@{11}: checkout: moving from develop to feature/UAL-117
f7fe845 HEAD@{12}: pull: Fast-forward
8c0136d HEAD@{13}: checkout: moving from feature/UAL-117 to develop
d238450 HEAD@{14}: checkout: moving from feature/UAL-117 to feature/UAL-117
d238450 HEAD@{15}: checkout: moving from develop to feature/UAL-117
8c0136d HEAD@{16}: checkout: moving from feature/UAL-117 to develop
d238450 HEAD@{17}: commit (merge): feature/UAL-117 update composer.lock
dd89670 HEAD@{18}: checkout: moving from develop to feature/UAL-117
```

Comment: Do you have a repo on some machine where you haven't fetched yet?

Comment: Dont worry. I believe you wont loose any commits. Can you put gitk graph or more information related to this?

Comment: Do you have branches in your repo?

Comment: @sergej I've other branches on my repo but none of them have the commits of this particular branch.

Comment: Does `git reflog` show the discarded commits?

Comment: @sergej added the output of that to the answer

Comment: Try `git reset --hard f7fe845` or so.

Comment: @sergej: That is the same command that caused the problem in the first place! Try `git reset --hard 8c0136d` instead.

Comment: @sergej that didnt get the previous version

Comment: @rodrigo that didnt bring the previous version

Comment: What was the message of the last commit you are trying to restore?

Comment: @sergej `git reset --hard f7fe845
HEAD is now at f7fe845 UAL-64: added search into the header` is going to a differen'ts branch commit

Comment: `git reset --hard 238450`?

Comment: @sergej i love you!, that worked!

Comment: @sergej: why not `6a03be3` like stas suggests?

Comment: @sergej please post your answer and I will accept that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run:

```
git reflog
```

And hope to see something like "`d238450 HEAD@{17}: commit ....`"
in the output.

And then:

```
git reset --hard <commit>
```

Where `<commit>` points to the snapshot you would like to restore (eg: `d238450`).

Answer (score 1):

If the problem is due to reseting to `f7fe845`, try

```
git reset --hard 6a03be3
```